# find and replace '%20' with a space in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble trying to figure this out,

basically I have a url string like so `this%20is%20a%20string` now what I want to do is find and replace all instances of `%20` and replace with a space so the string then becomes `this is a string`.

Now I've tried to do something like this..

```
if(string.includes('%20')) {
   const arr = str.split('%20');
}
```

which splits the string into an array, but I'm not sure how I can then turn the array of seperate strings into a full string with spaces between each word.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `decodeURI("this%20is%20a%20string")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regex,

```
str.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! I will accept this answer is 10 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Just use `join`:

```
str.split('%20').join(" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let val = "this%20is%20a%20string".replace(/%20/g, ' ');
alert(val);
```

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)